# Binomial distribution probability that the 45th student selected will be the 38th student to select yes?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

[image]

I figured out part a and part b, but I cannot get my head around how to do part c. Any help, please!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please put the effort of typing a question. Linking pictures is strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Among the first $44$ students, you must get $37$ yes's followed by a yes on the $45^{th}$.